# chmod u-x problem in case statement in Shell Script

Tags: bash, chmod

[image]

I want to give rights to a file using a menu (exec,write,read).
If you look closely I read value B( the file's name) then I use the `case` function to do the 1)exec / 2)write / 3)read function for that file with another `case`'s.

I have an error on the line:

```
chmod u-x $b" ; ls -l ;
```

when I execute the `.sh`.  Why? I will attach a screenshot with the error.

[image]!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the actual code. There's no reason anybody should "look closely" at images of text, when they can look at the text itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `case` statement syatax is not right.

In `case` statement every pattern-action pair needs to be ended in `;;` but you have used a single `;` (after `ls -l`) which is analogous to newline in this case. So, the shell is continuing with the same pattern-action pair in the next line, found `2)` and shown a syntax error.

The correct syntax would be:

```bsh
case "$c" in 
          1) chmod u+x "$b"; ls -l ;;
```

Check [this tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case) to get more idea on the `case` statement.

Also note that there must be no spaces between permission bit syntax i.e. you need to put `u+x`, not `u + x`.

Comment: OMG I forgot that the case ended there ;) Thx !

Comment: @CiobanuRares Happy to help..please consider copy-pasting from terminal rather than posting screenshots..  :)

Comment: Ok.. I have another problem now . Error : chmod : invalid mode 'u'.What should I do now ? Can you tell me please?

Comment: @CiobanuRares there must be no spaces between permission bit syntax i.e. you need to put `u+x`, not `u + x`..added this to answer too..